# LinkedIn API get all employees in company?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to get a list of all employees in a company? Not only in the current users network. Like this search returns:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?company-name=Apple
```

This is possible on the main LinkedIn site so i can't see why it wouldn't be in the API?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the **'company-name'** field selector and set the **'current-company'** field selector to **True** in order to retrieve employees in your network:

```
GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?company-name=Apple&current-company=true
```

This will fetch all employees at Apple who are currently working there.

But ,People Search API is a part of LinkedIn's Vetted API Access Program. You must apply [here](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr) and get LinkedIn's approval before using this API.

Comment: this people search api seems disabled by linkedin?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be gone.