# How can I retrieve a list of all employees within a company through the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Years ago, someone [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785854/linkedin-api-get-all-employees-in-company) if it were possible to retrieve a list of all employees who work at a company. I can do this through the LinkedIn UI, but I cannot seem to find any mechanism for this using the v2 API. The SO response mentions this used to be possible on the v1 API, but you had to request access through LinkedIn's "Vetted API Access Program." Unfortunately, the link on this response is now obsolete and does not send users to any such program.

How could I apply for this program nowadays? This is a specific situation to me and my company, so I would very much like to discuss this with someone at LinkedIn if some form of this Vetted API Access Program still exists. I do not wish to disclose the details of this request to the open internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have confirmed through contacts inside LinkedIn that this API functionality has been removed. No further information has been provided, and LinkedIn tech support refuses to comment any more on this issue. Furthermore, no LinkedIn engineers will comment on this thread here.

This is bizarre since any regular user can do this functionality through the web front-end, but for some reason LinkedIn believes this would be a violation of privacy/security if we could do this programmatically.

Therefore, the only way to obtain this data would be through screen scraping. I wish I had better news, and I wish that LinkedIn would provide some reasoning for their changes, but alas this is where we are.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a very similar question because I ran into the same problem as you.

The application forms for Linkedin's current partner programs seem to be located [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply), however I can't tell you which one of those programs comes with the necessary API access rights and I am in general not sure if this API request is still allowed.

Edit: The Linkedin Help page [states](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/topics/6400/6401/97491) that applications for partner programs are currently unavailable?

Comment: Yup I found the same page! I contacted LinkedIn support but they basically said they didn't know anything about this and that I would have to rely on Stack Overflow for help. Sometimes I miss phone numbers on web sites.

Comment: Funny that they explicitly refer to Stack Overflow - my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282196/which-linkedin-api-allows-retrieving-people-working-at-a-company) was quickly flagged as off-topic ;)